# Node mailer not sending emails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, nodemailer

I was trying to set up a email verification method using nodemailer but it seems to not work for some reason. Can anyone find a fix ?
i will first generate the token and then send it to the user for them to verify their email and continue login process. I seem to be stuck in this part. Node mailer not sending the email but user registration info does save in the database.

my register route -

```
const User = require('../models/User');
 
const router = require('express').Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Token = require('../models/token');
 
 
router.post('/register', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
        // create and save user
        await user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({msg: err.message});
            }
        });
        // genereate token and save
        let token = new Token({_userId: user._id, token: crypto.getRandomValues(16).toString('hex')});
        token.save(() => {
            if(err) {
                return res.status(500).send({msg: err.message});
            }
 
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({service: 'gmail', auth: {user: 'myEmail', pass: "Password"}});
            let mailOptions = {from: "authmail14@gmail.com", to: user.email, subject: "Account Verification Link"}
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(500).send({msg: "Technical Issue"})
                }
                return res.status(200).send('Email Sent')
            })
        });
    } catch {
        console.log("NO result")
    }
});
 
module.exports = router;
```

tokenSchema -

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 
const tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "user"},
    token: {type: String, required: true},
    expiredAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), index: {expires: 86400000}}
});
 
const token = mongoose.model('token', tokenSchema);
 
module.exports = token;
```

userSchema -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, required: true, minlength: 5,maxlength:30
    },
    email: {
        type: String, unique:true, maxlength:30
    },
    password: {
        type: String, minlength: 8, required:true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean, default: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    verified: {
        type: Boolean, default: false
    }
});
```

app.js -

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
 
 
dotenv.config();
 
const app = express();
 
 
app.use(express.json());
 
app.use('/auth', authRoute);
 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO).then(() => {
    console.log('Database Connected')
});
 
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") { 
    app.use(express.static("client/build")); 
    app.get("*", (req, res) => { 
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}
 
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Online at ${PORT}`);
});
     
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code doesn't send the email. it returns "NO Result"

Comment: Using `catch { console.log("NO result") }` is rather stupid. You should better use `catch (err) { console.log(err.message) }` or `catch (err) { console.log(err.stack) }` Most likely then you will see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because `transporter.sendMail()` is asynchronous function you have to use `async await` to execute that function.

Try this

```
 token.save(async () => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).send({msg: err.message});
        }

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({service: 'gmail', auth: {user: 'myEmail', pass: "Password"}});
        let mailOptions = {from: "authmail14@gmail.com", to: user.email, subject: "Account Verification Link"}
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return res.status(500).send({msg: "Technical Issue"})
            }
            return res.status(200).send('Email Sent')
        })
    });
```

Comment: i dont think it works.

Comment: Did you try it.

Comment: yes i did add the line you said. it returns "await is only valid in async function and the top level bodies of modules"

do i have to call the infoMail variable somewhere?

Comment: ok that means you are using `await` without applying `async` to the function.

Comment: Can you kindly check the code ? im trying to learn authentication and dont have much understanding of it.

Comment: ok  I will check it out.

Comment: I'm editing my answer, Get the code from there.

Comment: i'm still getting "no result" after applying your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dharmik Patel's answer problematic

Either you use async/await to run synchronous code, or you use a callbak or promise for asynchronous code.

But not both at the same time.

Here is an example with callback :

```
mailer.transport.sendMail( mail_config, function( error ) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.info( 'Mail not sent : ', error );
    return;
  }
  
  console.info( 'Mail sent ! ');
  message.transport.close();
});
```

Just add console for printing error of mailler callback to see what is the problem.

In general, use promises or calbacks instead to keep the asynchronous advantage of node.js.

Synchronous operation must be reserved for processing that cannot be done asynchronously.